# Why can $\tan$ have every real number as its value?

Tags: trigonometry

If $\tan\theta=\frac{\sin\theta}{\cos\theta}$, and $\sin\theta,\cos\theta \in [-1,1]$, how can $f:(-\pi/2,\pi/2)\to\mathbb{R}:x\mapsto\tan(x)$ be surjective? How can we find for any $y\in\mathbb{R}$ an $x$ such that $\tan(x)=y$?

Comment: What thing _other than_ a (real) number would you expect it to be?

Comment: I don't, but how it can be _any_ real number?

Comment: For all $\cos(\theta)\neq0$, so $\theta\neq\frac{\pi}{2}+k\pi, k\in\mathbb{Z}$, $\tan$ is defined, and of course it is in $\mathbb{R}$ as the fraction of two reals...

Comment: Just to give one example of $\tan\theta$ being a real number, consider, $\theta=\pi/4$ or $45^\circ$. Then $\tan\theta$ is $1$, because $\sin\theta$ and $\cos\theta$ are both $1/\sqrt2$ and $\frac{1/\sqrt2}{1/\sqrt2}=1$. And $1$ is certainly a real number.

Comment: Yes. I know that $\tan 90^\circ$ is undefined.

Comment: If your question is why $f:(-\pi/2,\pi/2)\to\mathbb{R}:x\mapsto\tan(x)$ is surjective, please edit your question.

Comment: Sayng $\tan(\theta)\in\Bbb R$ does not imply that $\tan(\theta)$ can be any real number. For example if $f(t)=1/(1+t^2)$ then $f(t)\in\Bbb R$ even though $f(t)$ _cannot_ be any real number...

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich Yes, I know but I don't know how to write that...

Comment: @HenningMakholm What I'm asking is how $\frac{\sin\theta}{\cos\theta}$ can produce any number from $\Bbb{R}$ if their allowed values are $[-1,1]$.

Comment: @Hanlon: I showed you how it can produce $1$. Do you deny that $1$ is an example of a number from $\mathbb R$? Do you, in general, claim, that dividing two real numbers cannot produce a real number?

Comment: "Yes, I know but I don't know how to write that... ": I have no idea what you mean.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich I don't know how to write that $\tan\theta$ can be any number from $\Bbb{R}$, not just that it is in $\Bbb{R}$.

Comment: Well, you just did :) However I proposed an edit, hope you don't mind.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich In math notation.

Comment: @Hanlon: Are you perhaps trying at ask whether _every_ number can be the value of $\tan\theta$, rather than simply ask whether there is _any_ real number that can be the value of $\tan\theta$?

Comment: @HenningMakholm  Yes. I don't understand how can for $a,b \in [-1,1]$ $a/b$ give any real number (for $b \neq 0$, of course).

Comment: @Hanlon: Then why do you keep writing "any" if you really mean "every"?

Comment: If @Hanlon is not a native speaker, I understand the confusion, but please make your question clearer next time. If you don't know how to write it in math notation, then just write it in English, because this way your question is confusing.

Comment: @HenningMakholm Because I mean it in sense _you can pick any real number and it can be a value for $\tan\theta$_. Contrast this with _you can pick any number from the interval $[-1,1]$ and it can be a value of $\sin\theta$, but you can't pick any number from $\Bbb{R}$ for $\sin\theta$_.

Comment: @VáclavMordvinov I'm not a native speaker, but I think I did say what I meant to say.

Comment: By the way, if someone understands what I'm asking, please edit the question to be precise enough, because I don't know how to make it precise enough.

Comment: @Hanlon: Suppose you ask someone "are there any seafood restaurants on Main Street?" and they answer "No -- it is true that some of the seafood restaurants are on Main Street, but there are a few seafood restaurants on Grove Street too". Would you then think they had understood your question correctly? That would only be a meaningful answer if your question had been "Are _all_ the seafood restaurants located on Main Street?"

Comment: @HenningMakholm No, I wouldn't.

Comment: @Hanlon: Suppose then you ask "are there any real numbers that are values of the tangent function?"

Comment: @HenningMakholm No, I don't mean that. I mean _are (and if they are how) the possible values for $\tan\theta$ all real numbers?_. This is different from _possible values for $\sin\theta$ are in the interval $[-1,1]$_. For example, if I present to you $\tan\theta$ and ask you what it can be, you'd say it can be any real number. If I ask you what $\sin\theta$ can be, you'd say it can be any number from the interval $[-1,1]$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be asking if $x$ and $y$ are bounded how can their ratios be unbounded.

And the answer to that is that if $y$ is very small and close to $0$ then $\frac 1y$ is very large, and although $\frac xy$ is not quiet as large as $\frac 1y$, it can still be quite large.

So it shouldn't surprise us that if 1) $\tan \theta$ is continuous.  and 2) $\tan \theta$ is (might be) unbounded (and could be both unbounded in the "positive" and "negative" directions-- an $\tan 0 = 0$) that we can conclude, by intermediate value theorem that A) $\tan$ is surjective.

But if you want something more direct:

Let $w$ be any real number.

Then $\sqrt{w^2 + 1} > \sqrt{w^2} = |w|$ so $|\frac {w}{\sqrt{w^2 + 1}}| < 1$.

So there exists a $\theta; -\frac \pi 2< \theta < \frac \pi 2$ so that $\sin \theta = \frac {w}{\sqrt{w^2 + 1}}$.

And $\cos \theta = \sqrt { 1 - (\frac {w}{\sqrt{w^2 + 1}}^2)} = \sqrt {1 - \frac {w^2}{w^2 + 1}} = \sqrt{\frac {w^2 + 1}{w^2 + 1} - \frac {w^2}{w^2 + 1}} = \sqrt {\frac 1{w^2 + 1}} = \frac 1{\sqrt{w^2 + 1}}$

There fore:

$\tan \theta = \frac {\sin \theta}{\cos \theta} = \frac {\frac w{\sqrt{w^2 + 1}}}{\frac 1{\sqrt{w^2 + 1}}} = w$.

And that's it.

So if I wanted to solve $\tan \theta = -9,827$, I would punch $\theta = \arcsin \frac {-9827}{\sqrt{(-9827^2 + 1)}} = \arcsin -0.99999999482240484906224130963566 =  -89.99416955537648186081352217411^{\circ}$ into a calculator.

And $\tan -89.99416955537648186081352217411^{\circ} = -9827$.

Maybe a more reasonable problem is $\tan \theta = 7$.  Punch in $\theta = \arcsin \frac{7}{\sqrt{50}} = 81.869897645844021296855612559093^\circ$. And $\tan 81.869897645844021296855612559093^\circ = 7$.

===== old, but complete calculations from scratch ====

Let $w \in \mathbb R$.  We want to solve $w = \frac x{\sqrt{1 - x^2}}$ where $|x| < 1$.

So $\sqrt{1-x^2}w = x$

$(1-x^2)w^2= x^2$ (Note: squaring gives us an extraneous answer so we will get two rather than one solution.  We will choose the one where $x$ and $w$ are the same sign.)

$(w^2+1)x^2 -w^2 = 0$

$x = \frac {0\pm \sqrt {0-4(-w^2)(w^2+1)}}{2(w^2 + 1)}= \frac {\pm 2|w|\sqrt{w^2+1}}{2(w^2+1)} = \frac w{\sqrt{w^2 + 1}}$

Note.  If $|w|< 1$ then $\sqrt{w^2 + 1} > 1>|w|$ so $|x| =  |\frac w{\sqrt{w^2 + 1}}| < 1$.  And if $|w| \ge 1$ then $\sqrt{w^2 + 1} > \sqrt{w^2} = |w|$ so $|x| =|\frac w{\sqrt{w^2 + 1}}| < 1$.

So let $x = \frac w{\sqrt{w^2 + 1}}$ and let $y = \sqrt{1 - x^2} = \sqrt {1 - \frac {w^2}{w^2 + 1}} = \sqrt{\frac {w^2 + 1}{w^2 + 1} - \frac {w^2}{w^2 + 1}} = \sqrt {\frac 1{w^2 + 1}} = \frac 1{\sqrt{w^2 + 1}}$

Then $\frac xy = w$ and $|x| < 1$ and $|y|< 1$.

Let $\theta = \sin^{-1} x =\sin^{-1}\frac w{\sqrt{w^2 + 1}}$ and therefore $y = \sqrt{1 - \sin^2 \theta} = \cos \theta$.

And $\tan \theta = \frac {\sin \theta}{\cos \theta} = \frac xy = w$.

So $\tan$ is surjective.

Answer (score 9):

Pick any number $m \in \Bbb R$ and draw a line of slope $m$ through the origin. Let $\theta$ be the angle from the $x$-axis to the line. Then $\tan\theta = m$.

Comment: Ohhh, that's why $\tan(\pi /2)$ is not defined :)

Answer (score 1):

In any right angled triangle , hypotenuse is the  longest side. see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypotenuse

i.e, opposite side,adjacent side $\lt$ hypotenuse 
$$\sin\theta=\frac{\text{opposite side}}{\text{hypotenuse}}$$ and $$\cos\theta=\frac{\text{adjacent side}}{ 
\text{hypotenuse}}$$

both of them are proper fraction.

but$$\tan\theta=\frac{\text{opposite side}}{\text{adjacent side}}$$ is need not a proper fraction.

Answer (score 0):

$\cos \theta$ can get very close to $0$.  When it does, $\sin \theta$ is very close to $\pm 1$.  Do you have any problem with the fact that $\frac 1x$ can be very large when $x$ is small?  Aside from the fact that $\tan \theta$ can be zero, it is the same thing.  The statement you are asking why is it true is not true.  $\tan \frac \pi 2 \not \in \Bbb R$, for example.

Answer (score 0):

It is quite simple. First, you can agree that the tangent function is continuous. Next, it can be arbitrarily large, both positive and negative. That suffices to state that it takes all real outputs.

An even easier argument would be that the tangent function  is the ratio between the legs of a right triangle. You can fix the side opposite to theta as 1 and the other as any real number. Hence, you are done.